# Get text of the selected select box and then add the text to an empty span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a selectbox

```
<select id="edit-field-article-category-tid" name="field_article_category_tid" class="form-select">
<option value="All" selected="selected">- Any -</option>
<option value="9">Press Releases</option>
<option value="13">-Product Announcements</option>
<option value="12">-Trade Show Announcements</option>
<option value="11">-Company News</option>
<option value="10">Case Studies</option>
<option value="159">Technical Resources</option>
</select>
```

Now I also have an empty span

```
<span class="art_cat"></span>
```

What I'm trying to do is, as soon as I select an option and/or change a selected option from the select box I want the SELECTED option TEXT(not value) to be "copied" to the empty span...

I wrote this code but I can't get it to work!! Can somebody please give me a hand.

```
var art_cat = jQuery('#edit-field-article-category-tid').val();
jQuery('span.art_cat').html(art_cat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$(this)` would be cleaner.

```
jQuery("select#edit-field-article-category-tid").change(function() {
    jQuery('span.art_cat').text($(this).find("option:selected").text()); 
});
```

Also, it's more efficient to select elements without the leading element type. You're essentially searching for `select` first and then searching for the ID in those selects it found, where you could just search for ID and it finds it immediately.

So:

```
jQuery("select#edit-field-article-category-tid")
```

Should really be:

```
jQuery("#edit-field-article-category-tid")
```

Comment: thank you for the comments, I did you like you wrote, it looks less and cleaner now ))

Answer (score 0):

Sorry found the solution, here is the code:

```
jQuery("select#edit-field-article-category-tid").change(function(){
var art_cat = jQuery('select#edit-field-article-category-tid option:selected').text();
jQuery('span.art_cat').html(art_cat); 
});    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('#edit-field-article-category-tid').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  jQuery('span.art_cat').text(selected);
})
```

This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/a8en4xaa/1/
and I hope this help you.

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers - it's not how SO works. If somebody has already written the same answer, don't repeat it 45 minutes later! You've actually made a mistake in yours and that's why I've downvoted you.

Comment: sorry @PaparazzoKid. I'm not trying to duplicate your answer. I just want to share my answer. I didn't mean too.